# Left align and right align within div in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, user-interface, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

What are some of the common ways to left align some text and right align some other text within a div container in bootstrap?

e.g.

```
Total cost                   $42
```

Above total cost should be left aligned text and $42 is right aligned text

Answer (score 986, accepted):

***2021 Update...***

**Bootstrap 5 (beta)**

For aligning within a flexbox div or `row`...

- `ml-auto` is now `ms-auto`
- `mr-auto` is now `me-auto`

For text align or floats..

- `text-left` is now `text-start`
- `text-right` is now `text-end`
- `float-left` is now `float-start`
- `float-right` is now `float-end`

**Bootstrap 4+**

- `pull-right` is now `float-right`
- `text-right` is the same as 3.x, and works for inline elements
- both `float-*` and `text-*` are [responsive](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/responsive-helpers/#responsive-floats) for different alignment at different widths (ie: `float-sm-right`)

The flexbox utils (eg:`justify-content-between`) can also be used for alignment:

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
      <div>
         left
      </div>
      <div>
         right
      </div>
 </div>
```

or, auto-margins (eg:`ml-auto`) in any flexbox container (row,navbar,card,d-flex,etc...)

```
<div class="d-flex">
      <div>
         left
      </div>
      <div class="ml-auto">
         right
      </div>
 </div>
```

[Bootstrap 4 Align Demo](http://www.codeply.com/go/cgvFxT8IkH)
[Bootstrap 4 Right Align Examples](https://www.codeply.com/go/nTobetXAwb)(float, flexbox, text-right, etc...)

---

**Bootstrap 3**

Use the `pull-right` class..

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">Total cost</div>
    <div class="col-md-6"><span class="pull-right">$42</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Bootstrap 3 Demo](http://bootply.com/121984)

You can also use the `text-right` class like this:

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">Total cost</div>
    <div class="col-md-6 text-right">$42</div>
  </div>
```

[Bootstrap 3 Demo 2](http://bootply.com/ZFNQhIEtL3)

Comment: For Bootstrap 3, for column, `text-right` worked for me.

Comment: for bootstrap 5
Renamed .text-left and .text-right to .text-start and .text-end.

Comment: What is the purpose of renaming classes in each version?

Comment: @FernandoKosh Changing from Left/Right to Start/End is because it adds support for Right-To-Left languages, and the padding, margins, and text justifications, and even the order of columns automatically flip when the page specifies a language that reads from the right.

Answer (score 66):

Instead of using `pull-right` class, it is better to use `text-right` class in the column, because `pull-right` creates problems sometimes while resizing the page.

Answer (score 27):

Bootstrap v4 introduces flexbox support

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
  <div class="mr-auto p-2">Flex item</div>
  <div class="p-2">Flex item</div>
  <div class="p-2">Flex item</div>
</div>
```

Learn more at https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/flexbox/

Answer (score 24):

<strike>In Bootstrap 4 the correct answer is to use the `text-xs-right` class.</strike>

This works because `xs` denotes the smallest viewport size in BS. If you wanted to, you could apply the alignment only when the viewport is medium or larger by using `text-md-right`.

In the latest alpha, `text-xs-right` has been simplified to `text-right`.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">Total cost</div>
    <div class="col-md-6 text-right">$42</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 16):

[bootstrap 5.0](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/#css)

- [float](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/float/)
- [row](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/grid/#row-columns)

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6"><p class="float-start">left</p></div>  
  <div class="col-sm-6"><p class="float-end">right</p></div>  
</div>
```

A whole column can accommodate 12, 6 (col-sm-`6`) is exactly half, and in this half, one to the left(`float-start`) and one to the right(`float-end`).

## more example

- fontawesome-button

  ```html
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-HK5fgLBL+xu6dm/Ii3z4xhlSUyZgTT9tuc/hSrtw6uzJOvgRr2a9jyxxT1ely+B+xFAmJKVSTbpM/CuL7qxO8w==" crossorigin="anonymous" />

  <div class="row">
    <div class=col-sm-6>
      <p class="float-start text-center">  <!-- text-center can help you put the icon at the center -->
        <a class="text-decoration-none" href="https://www.google.com/"
        ><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-left fa-3x"></i><br>Left
        </a>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class=col-sm-6>
      <p class="float-end text-center">
        <a class="text-decoration-none" href="https://www.google.com/"
        ><i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right fa-3x"></i><br>Right
        </a>
      </p>
    </div>
  ```

Comment: Bootstrap 5 (beta) replaced "text-right" by "text-end" and "text-left" by "text-start". "text-center" stayed.

Comment: Only this worked for me, using bootstrap 5

Comment: Thanx - Just stumbled across this as well..

Answer (score 9):

We can achieve by Bootstrap 4 Flexbox:

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-between w-100">
<p>TotalCost</p> <p>$42</p>
</div>

d-flex // Display Flex
justify-content-between // justify-content:space-between
w-100 // width:100%
```

Example: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pradeep0594/q0uvLoug/)

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">Total cost</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4"></div>
  <div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">$42</div>
</div>
```

That should do the job just ok

Comment: Thanks. What bootstrap version is this ?

Comment: @jovialcore you are welcome. It is version 3

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col float-start">
        Total Cost
    </div>
    <div class="col float-end">
        42
    </div>
</div>
```

This will work and is simple to understand. In the class attribute, I have used Bootstrap 5 classes.