# How to align two col to the right? bootstrap 3 grid

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have three columns displayed in one row, I need to align last two to the right corner, it works fine with one column but when I try to pull-right two it messes up grid and pushes elements to the next row down.
The question is how to align one column to the right and other next to it.

```
       <div class="row ">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                    ...
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-3" >
                     ...
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-5 pull-right">
                        <div class=" pull-right">
                          ...
                        </div>
                    </div>
        </div>
```

Current:

```
|[     ]       [      ]       [     ]|
```

Wanted:

```
|[     ]              [      ][     ]|
```

Comment: Can't you just add `pull-right` to the middle column?

Comment: It first thing I tried,middle col goes to right-corner and right col goes to the next line down.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Left align and right align within div in Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18672452/left-align-and-right-align-within-div-in-bootstrap)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It depends on whether you're right aligning text inside the middle column, or some another container inside the column.. Here are a few examples that may work for you..

http://www.bootply.com/119747

```
<div class="row ">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    1 text here 
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3 text-right">
    2 text here 
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-5">
    3 text here 
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row ">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="well"> 
      content
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="well pull-right"> 
      content pull-right 
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-5">
    <div class="well"> 
      content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Use lower col size with offset like this:

```
<div class="col-sm-3"></div>
<div class="col-sm-3 offset-col-sm-3"></div>
<div class="col-sm-3"></div>
```