# text-center and text-right not working in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want some elements on my page to align to the center and right, but the bootstrap classes 'text-right' and 'text-center' don't seem to work, even though 'text-left' does.

Thanks.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row text-center" id="header">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="container" style="padding-left:30px; padding-right:30px;">
                <div class="col-xs-2 text-left" id="mainLogo">
                    <a href="/"><img src="/stylesheet/main_logo.png" ></a>
                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-6 text-right">
                    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                        <li role="presentation" class="dropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Account <span class="caret"></span>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <li id="ctl00">
                                    <a href="/account/">Your Account</a>
                                </li>
                                <li id="user">
                                    <a href="/profile/">Profile</a>
                                </li>
                                <li id="panel">
                                    <a href="/shop/reviewbasket/">Basket</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-4 text-right">
                    <div id="search">
                 </div>     
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You should be able to use your browser's developer console (the "inspector") to see the style rules that are being applied, and where the breakdown is taking place.  `text-right` and `text-center` do work, but may not at such a high level.  You likely need to put it on each `a` within your nav ul

Comment: I think it is working, refer to this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/f0wL18zy/ hello is in center

Comment: For future readers using Bootstrap 5 see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18672452/left-align-and-right-align-within-div-in-bootstrap/18672475#18672475

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**Bootstrap 5 - Update 2022**

As [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18672452/left-align-and-right-align-within-div-in-bootstrap/18672475#18672475), **left** & **right** have been replaced with **start** & **end** in Bootstrap 5...

- use `float-end` on a block elements (ie: `div`)
- use `text-end` on inline elements (ie: `a`, `span`)

**Bootstrap 4 - Update 2018**

`pull-right` has changed to `float-right`

**Bootstrap 3 - Original Answer**

The original question was for Bootstrap 3 and the problem was that the OP was attempting to use text-right on a block element. `text-right` only works on inline elements. UL is a block element so you'd use `pull-right` like this..

```
<div class="col-xs-6">
     <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right"> 
         ...
```

Answer (score 128):

For those using Bootstrap 5 be aware that `text-left` and `text-right` classes have been removed. Now you can use `text-start` and `text-end`.

Comment: The problem I'm having right now is that text-start is giving me right-alignment and text-end is giving me left-alignment.

Comment: @LiterateCorvette please ask a new question about it and create a test case.

Comment: Can you provide the link of the documentation? I tried to find and still appears text-left and right

Comment: This worked like a charm on bootstrap 5!