# Show a text content as left aligned in Bootstrap 5 Modal footer

Tags: bootstrap-5

I have a Bootstrap Modal. In the footer, a text content that should be aligned in left and a close button that should be aligned in right.

But by default, both are aligned in right.

```
<div class="modal-footer">
  <h6 class="modal-title" id="modalLblBtm" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 255);">Booking No#</h6>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>                     
</div>
```

What class could be added to align both items vertically?

Appreciate if anybody could help on this!

Answer (score 8):

**Use me-auto on the left button.**

```cs
<div class="modal-footer">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary me-auto">Save changes</button>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
</div>
```

For more info check: [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18672452/left-align-and-right-align-within-div-in-bootstrap/18672475)

Comment: I've added `ms-auto` class in my Close button and it's worked @Divyesh_08. Just posted as a separate answer.

Comment: great, you got the answer!

Comment: This also works on other elements (e.g. a label).

Comment: it's not working for  2 button at left and 1 at right.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution by search around in Bootstrap site!

As mentioned by @Divyesh_08, we could add `mr-auto` class. But, it will work until `Bootstrap-4`. In `Bootstrap-5`, the class name has been changed as `ms-auto`.

> start: left, end: right, center: center

So, I've updated my code. It should be as below to align vertically.

```
<div class="modal-footer">
      <h6 class="modal-title" id="modalLblBtm" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 255);">Booking No#</h6>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal  ms-auto">Close</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue. I've used `mr-auto` in Bootstrap-5. Now, I got the answer. It should be `ms-auto`. Thanks