# Align Columns Right in Bootsrap 5

Tags: html, css

I want to align the 2 fields that are Left Bottom (Currency I Want:, Amount) to Right Top in Bootsrap 5. I have spent tons of hours and cannot figure out! Could you help me?

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Yjdu.jpg [1]

My code is the following:

````
return (
 <div className="card card-body p-3 mb-2 bg-light text-dark">
  <h1>Currency Converter</h1>
    <form>
      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
          <label>Currency I have:</label>
          <select className="form-select" type="text" >
            <option value="1" selected >USD</option>
            <option value="2">EUR</option>
            <option value="3">GBP</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div className="form-group col-md-4">
          <label>Amount:</label>
          <input type="number" className="form-control"/>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="form-row">
        <div className="form-group col-md-4">
          <label>Currency I Want:</label>
          <select className="form-select" type="text" >
            <option value="1" selected >USD</option>
            <option value="2">EUR</option>
            <option value="3">GBP</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div className="form-group col-md-4">
          <label>Amount:</label>
          <input type="number" className="form-control"/>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" className="btn btn-secondary mb-2">Convert</button>
    </form>
  </div>
);
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

Create a new div that shares both columns and add `d-flex` class to it.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="card card-body p-3 mb-2 bg-light text-dark">
  <h1>Currency Converter</h1>
    <form>
      <div class="d-flex">
      <div class="form-row col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group col-md-8">
          <label>Currency I have:</label>
          <select class="form-select" type="text" >
            <option value="1" selected >USD</option>
            <option value="2">EUR</option>
            <option value="3">GBP</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-8">
          <label>Amount:</label>
          <input type="number" class="form-control"/>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-row col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group col-md-8">
          <label>Currency I Want:</label>
          <select class="form-select" type="text" >
            <option value="1" selected >USD</option>
            <option value="2">EUR</option>
            <option value="3">GBP</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-8">
          <label>Amount:</label>
          <input type="number" class="form-control"/>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      <br/>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary mb-2">Convert</button>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

***float-end* using in form row**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div className="card card-body p-3 mb-2 bg-light text-dark float-right">
  <h1>Currency Converter</h1>
  <br>

    <form>
        <div class="form-row float-end">
           
           <div class="form-group col-md-4">
              <label>Currency I have:</label>
               <select className="form-select" type="text" >
                  <option value="1" selected >USD</option>
                  <option value="2">EUR</option>
                  <option value="3">GBP</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <div className="form-group col-md-4 float-end">
            <label>Amount:</label>
            <input type="number" className="form-control"/>
          </div><br>
        </div>
         
        <div className="form-row">
          <div className="form-group col-md-4">
            <label>Currency I Want:</label>
            <select className="form-select" type="text" >
              <option value="1" selected >USD</option>
              <option value="2">EUR</option>
              <option value="3">GBP</option>
            </select>
          </div><br/>
          <div className="form-group col-md-4 ">
            <label>Amount:</label>
            <input type="number" className="form-control"/>
          </div><br/>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-secondary mb-2">Convert</button>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Check Out [More Details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18672475/12635334)

Answer (score 0):

How Can I Push the 2 rows Right to the end with the Button in middle?

[My updated image after the answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btDu3.jpg)

My source code:

````
  return (
    <div class="card card-body p-3 mb-2 bg-light text-dark">
      <h1>Currency Converter</h1>
        <form>
          <div class="d-flex">
          <div class="form-row col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            <div class="form-group col-md-8">
              <label>Currency I Have:</label>
              <select class="form-select" type="text" >
                <option value="1" selected >USD</option>
                <option value="2">EUR</option>
                <option value="3">GBP</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-8">
              <label>Amount:</label>
              <input type="number" class="form-control"/>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-row col-md-6 col-sm-6 float-right">
            <div class="form-group col-md-8">
              <label>Currency I Want:</label>
              <select class="form-select" type="text" >
                <option value="1" selected >USD</option>
                <option value="2">EUR</option>
                <option value="3">GBP</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-8">
              <label>Amount:</label>
              <input type="number" class="form-control"/>
            </div>
          </div>
          </div>
          <br/>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary mb-2">Convert</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }```
````

Answer (score -1):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="card card-body p-3 mb-2 bg-light text-dark">
  <h1>Currency Converter</h1>
    <form>
      <div class="d-flex">
      <div class="form-row col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group col-md-8">
          <label>Currency I have:</label>
          <select class="form-select" type="text" >
            <option value="1" selected >USD</option>
            <option value="2">EUR</option>
            <option value="3">GBP</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-8">
          <label>Amount:</label>
          <input type="number" class="form-control"/>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-row col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group col-md-8">
          <label>Currency I Want:</label>
          <select class="form-select" type="text" >
            <option value="1" selected >USD</option>
            <option value="2">EUR</option>
            <option value="3">GBP</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-8">
          <label>Amount:</label>
          <input type="number" class="form-control"/>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      <br/>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary mb-2">Convert</button>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Thank you, this did the trick!