# Getting text in a Bootstrap 5 card header right aligned

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I have a card in Bootstrap 5, and I would like some of the contents of the header to be right aligned, and the other content to be left aligned.  So far everything is left-aligned, no matter what I do.

Here's some sample code:

```
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
      <a href="/users">Users</a>
      <span class="text-end text-muted">
             48
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
       <p>Card content</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

So far in the `span` I have tried `text-end`, `float-right`, and `pull-right` but it has no effect.  Everything is left-aligned.

Thank you so much for your help everyone.

Also, there are several questions about this type of topic, but most of the examples are in Bootstrap 4.  Am looking for something specific to Bootstrap 5, since the bootstrap 4 examples do not seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are other Bootstrap 5 answers [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18672452/). All uses of **left** and **right** have been replaced with **start** and **end** in Bootstrap 5 for RTL support...

In your case the easiest way is to use `float-end`...

```
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
            <a href="/users">Users</a>
            <span class="float-end text-muted"> 48 </span>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <p>Card content</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Or, make the card-header flexbox using `d-flex` and then auto margin (`ms-auto`)...

```
   <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header d-flex">
            <a href="/users">Users</a>
            <span class="ms-auto text-muted"> 48 </span>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <p>Card content</p>
        </div>
   </div>
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/PWNGaSriFm)

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with [Flex](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/flex/).
Apply `.d-flex` to the `.card-header` then `.ms-auto` to the `<span>` you want to be on the right.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header d-flex">
    <a href="/users">Users</a>
    <span class="ms-auto text-muted">48</span>
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <p>Card content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="card ">
    <div class=" card-header">
        <a href="/users">Users</a>
        <span class="float-end text-muted">
            48
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <p>Card content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

Yo can also move the contents of the header to be right

```
  <div class="card ">
        <div class=" card-header text-end">
            <a href="/users">Users</a>
            <span class="float-end text-muted">
                48
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <p>Card content</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```